# Django. Статистика на сайте цитат

Tags: python, django

Есть проект - сайт, в котором пользователи могут постить цитаты, указывать автора цитаты и добавлять к ним категории. Смысл в том, что это будет сайт для ограниченного числа людей, поэтому определенные юзеры уже будут указаны в базе данных, то есть фиксированное число пользователей, больше не будет. Эти то юзеры и будут авторами данных цитат, а также редакторами: один человек что-то сказал(автор цитаты), второй(редактор цитаты) это запостил на сайте и указал автора. Так вот, мне бы хотелось иметь связь между Автором(не редактором) и цитатой, к которой его отнесли. Идея такая, чтобы у определенного юзера имелась статистика, в которой есть информация о том, к какой Категории цитат чаще приписывают Автора. Например, из категорий цитат "любовь", "смех" и "грусть" меня бы чаще заносили в Категорию "смех", ведь я чаще шучу, соответственно, цитаты на сайте, скорее всего, имели бы похожую категорию.

```py
from django.db import models
from author.models import Profile


class QuotesHonors(models.Model):
    quotes = models.TextField()
    editor = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                               related_name='quotes_editor')
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                               related_name='quotes_author')
    category = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='quotes_category')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.quotes[:30])


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.title)


class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='user_like')
    quotes = models.ForeignKey(QuotesHonors, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quotes_like')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='user_comment')
    quotes = models.ForeignKey(QuotesHonors, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quotes_comment')
    body = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    # avatar = models.ImageField(default='avatars/gosling.jpg', upload_to='avatars/')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.first_name) + ' ' + str(self.last_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давно не писал запросы в DjangoORM, но, что-то близкое к вашему решению будет выглядеть так:
предположим, что `user` это объект модели `Profile`, тогда
запрос `user.quotes_author.all()` вернет вам `QuerySet` из всех цитат пользователя. Tак как нам нужно узнать какая категория пользуется популярностью, добавим в выборку только интересующее нас поле:
`user.quotes_author.all().values('category')`

Далее, подсчитаем количество цитат в каждой категории и отсортируем по убыванию:

```
from django.db.models import Count
user.quotes_author.all().values('category').annotate(total=Count('category')).order_by('total')
```

В результате вернется `QuerySet` с категориями, отсортированными по убыванию, т.е. самая популярная будет на 0 позиции. Можно получить ее сразу, добавив `.first()` метод к запросу.

Более подробно про `values` почитать [тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#values), про `annotate` [тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#annotate), а про `Count` - [тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#id9).

Comment: Спасибо большое. Про annotate было супер полезно!

Comment: @hg, так же советую почитать про `select_related` и `prefetch_related`,чтобы уменьшить количество запросов к БД